# Splitting A List At Certain Characer

Tags: python

say I have a list that goes something like this:

```
['Try not to become a man of success, but rather try to become a man of value.
\n', 'Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything 
better.\n', 'The true sign of intelligence is not knowledge but imagination.
\n', 'We cannot solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we 
created them. \n', 'Weakness of attitude becomes weakness of character.\n', 
"You can't blame gravity for falling in love. \n", 'The difference between 
stupidity and genius is that genius has its limits. \n']
```

How would I go about splitting this list into sub-lists at every newline? 
How do I turn the output above to my desired output below?

```
['Try not to become a man of success, but rather try to become a man of value.'] 
['Look deep into nature, and then you will understand everything better']  ['The true sign of intelligence is not knowledge but imagination.]
```

Comment: Your list already looks split, see the comma's in your first example, do you want to make list of lists (containing only one string)?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. In case you want to remove the new line character `\n` and turn each element into its own list: `[[phrase.strip()] for phrase in arr]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result seems like a list of item where each item is a list containing a single element composed of the list item stripped of whitespaces, something that can be achieved using:

```
result = [[line.strip()] for line in lines]
```